# Permutation problem : Blocks of Seats

Tags: combinatorics

**Question** : In a row of 20 seats, in how many ways can 3 blocks of consecutive seats with 5 seats in each block be selected?

**Solution :**
You can think of each block as a single unit, so altogether there are 
3 + 5 = 8 objects to be considered

There are 8 objects to be arranged, 3 alike of one kind and 5 alike 
of a second kind.  The number of arrangements is  8!/(3! 5!) = 56

This is just the way the blocks can be chosen, we consider that 
individual seats within a block are indistinguishable.

**What I don't understand** : To me 8!/(3! 5!) looks similar to **answer** of the arrangement problem "how many distinct arrangements can be made of the word **SSSAAAAA** ?"
But the question is about selection right. Why there is arrangement in the solution?

What am I missing?
Can someone explain the solution please?

Comment: It very much is the same question as the arrangements of letters in "SSSAAAAA."  S represents 5-seat blocks, and A represents "free seats" that are not committed to a 5-seat block.

Comment: @Doug These 5 As can also form a block right? In that case can't we do 4C3?

Comment: They could, but they don't have to.  And you are going to start over counting if you think of them both as a block and not as a block.

Comment: You seem to mean two different things when saying "arrangement" and "selection"; could you please clarify what they mean to you (as this distinction seems to be at the heart of the question)?

Comment: @Doug Sorry I'm not getting this "both as a block and not as a block" part.

Comment: @Lovsovs Permutation means arrangement of things. The word arrangement is used, if the order of things is considered. Combination means selection of things. The word selection is used, when the order of things has no importance.

Comment: Okay. In your example of SSSAAAAA, can you tell the individual S's (or A's) apart?

Comment: @Lovsovs No. I can't because they both are same.

Comment: Exactly. That is why it is a combinatorics problem, and not a permutation.

Comment: @Doug Can you please elaborate? I'm not able to visualize.

Comment: This question can be modeled with 4 blocks of seats that are represented by "S" and 5 seats represented by "A", in the question, how many ways can we arrange the letters SSSAAAAA.  Yes it is possible that the 5 A's form into a block, in 4 of the arrangements, but that is pretty much irrelevant.  The ${8\choose 3}$ solution accounts for that possibility.